# UI issue with lightning buttonMenu variant after Winter 20 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have a borderless button menu with a specified button icon set up in a custom lightning component. Since the Winter 20 release the icon is displaying with a border and padding/margins seem to be different.

[image: Styles before and after Winter 20 release]

We are using variant="container" and setting a standard utility icon.

The border only appears when specifying a button icon, otherwise the variant attribute behaves as expected:

```
<lightning:buttonMenu aura:id="menu"  
                      variant="container" 
                      iconName="utility:add" 
                      iconSize="small">
    <lightning:menuItem value="MenuItemOne" label="Menu Item One" />
    <lightning:menuItem value="MenuItemTwo" label="Menu Item Two" />
</lightning:buttonMenu>
<br/><br/>
<lightning:buttonMenu aura:id="menu"
                      variant="container">
    <lightning:menuItem value="MenuItemOne" label="Menu Item One" />
    <lightning:menuItem value="MenuItemTwo" label="Menu Item Two" />
</lightning:buttonMenu>
```

[image: Sample button menus with and without specified button icon]

Has anyone come across this and figured out how to work around it? I don't want to apply compensating styles only for it to change again in the next release!

Comment: Since the Spring 20 release a few days ago the problem has disappeared in our sandbox (without making any changes).Great.

Answer (score 0):

in your case issue with `variant`/ `iconSize`, container variant takes 32PX by 32 PX button space, i would recommended to go through [button variant](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_variants.htm). in [winter 20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_aura_components.htm) release notes also they didn't mention about variant changes. so at this point workaround for this issue.
you can change  either `iconSize` to `large` or  `variant` to `bare`

[image]

**Tested CMP**

```
<lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layoutItem  padding="around-small">
        <lightning:buttonMenu aura:id="menu"  
                              variant="bare" 
                              iconName="utility:add" 
                              iconSize="small">
            <lightning:menuItem value="BareItemOne" label="Bare Item One" />
            <lightning:menuItem value="BareItemTwo" label="Bare Item Two" />
        </lightning:buttonMenu>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem  padding="around-small">
        <lightning:buttonMenu aura:id="menu1"
                              variant="container"
                              iconName="utility:add"
                              iconSize="large">
            <lightning:menuItem value="ContainerItemOne" label="Container Item One" />
            <lightning:menuItem value="ContainerItemTwo" label="Container Item Two" />
        </lightning:buttonMenu>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem  padding="around-small">
        <lightning:buttonMenu aura:id="menu2"
                              variant="container"
                              iconName="utility:add"
                              iconSize="small">
            <lightning:menuItem value="ContainersmallItemOne" label="Container small Item One" />
            <lightning:menuItem value="ContainersmallItemTwo" label="Container small Item Two" />
        </lightning:buttonMenu>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Unfortunately changing the variant type doesn't remove the border for me (nor does updating/removing the icon size).

Comment: may i know, which parent base component you used for `lightning:buttonMenu` ?

Comment: While testing I just created a new Lightning Application (Lightning Bundle) and previewed the markup. <aura:application extends="force:slds">.

In production the menu is in a Lightning Component (aura:component) - an older version, 44, but I have tried updating the version and it doesn't help.